# How to fetch data from firebase to recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I have an app, where I try to implement a function that would allow to create posts like in facebook. So, I want to create recyclerview that would fetch a data and display it on the screen when the post is created.

How do I do this?

I've written a code for this. But I get an error that in EventRecyclerAdapter.java in 40th line of code .get(position) is called on null reference object.

https://github.com/garaanon/IACS Here you can see the .java file I am referencing

Answer (score 0):

Your Else Condition will trigger when the Data is Null than why are you trying to get Description When it is Null.Remove the getDesc() from Else Condition will Remove Error.